# Create a global variables file and access it everywhere in Rails app; models, controllers and delayed jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, global-variables

I have some 40 variables defined like:--

```
 add_notice_sender = "You added %s to the %s group." 
 add_notice_everyone = "%s added %s to the %s group."
 accept_everyone = "%s has joined the %s group."
```

I will be replacing %s with values in various places may be in controller or model or delayed job. How can I create a single file for these kind of variables and use it from there only. I don't want to place it here and there in whole application.

- I tried in initializers directory but delayed job is not accessing it.
- I tried placing it in a file under lib directory. still no luck.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `config/locales/en.yml` and the `I18n` API for this?

Comment: @Benoit No. I dont know about that

Comment: Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html. This is designed to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you taking about something like this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml. If yes then how will i access them? is there any specific thing I have to do?

Comment: @Mohit Yes, something like this. It's built into rails and will also allow you to translate your application in multiple languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Benoit Garret's  comment:-

config/locales/en.yml and the I18n is the right place to have these kind of variable declarations.